# What is the BibTeX category of a monograph that appeared in a series?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I would like to cite the following book (the author refers to the work as book several times), which appeared in a series:

http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-1740-9

On the very first page of the PDF document I read "[...] the series: *Interdisciplinary Applied Mathematics*" and then "The series will consist of monographs and high-level texts from researchers [...]". The PDF file has 492 pages.

I would like to refer to the entire book. If I put it into the `INCOLLECTION` category I get:

`Warning--empty pages in Seydel10`

If I put it into the `BOOK` category I get

`Warning--can't use both author and editor fields in Seydel10`

The BibTeX entry is:

```
@BOOK{Seydel10,
  AUTHOR = {R{\"u}diger Seydel},
  EDITOR = {S.S. Antman and L. Sirovich and J.E. Marsden},
  TITLE = {{Practical Bifurcation and Stability Analysis}},
  SERIES = {{Interdisciplinary Applied Mathematics}},
  VOLUME = {5},
  YEAR = {2010},
  PUBLISHER = {{Dordrecht, The Netherlands: Springer}}
}
```

**How do I refer to this book properly?**

---

Edit: OK, apparently the `.bst` file is also important, I did not know that, sorry.

`\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}`

and is downloadable from [here](http://download.river-valley.com/elsarticle/elsarticle-harv.bst).

---

I got two excellent answers, they both answer my concerns. I decided to accept Bernard's answer because he "only" has 9.3k reputation points and Mico already has 74k at the time of writing.

Comment: Are the editors in your entry the editors of the series?  If so, you do not need to mention their names normally. As for the "can't use both author and editor fields": that's a feature of the `.bst` you are using, about which, unless you modify it, there's nothing to be done. (Well, that or choose a different  `.bst`.)  Also, depending on the style, if that is the 5th book in the series, it might be that you need to use the `number` field rather than the `volume` field.  Finally, don't forget that a "warning" is not an "error": it is best to fix warnings, but one is usually not a show-stopper.

Comment: According to the 3. page of the document they are "Series Editors" so I guess yes. The `.bst` is a given, I have to use it and I have no control over it. The `number` field doesn't seem right, I get "No. 5" in the generated bibliography and the original PDF file explicitly says "Volume 5". It is the volume of the series. The warning is annoying and it might signal that I am using the wrong category for the item, hence the question.

Comment: Right: well, your `.bst` does not cater to including series editors, so you have to skip it or hardwrire it in there via a field like `note` if you really want it.  (But it is probably unnecessary, though I don't work in any mathematics field, so....)  As for `number`, it was just a suggestion: when you don't mention the actual `.bst`, I can only offer guesses as to what's going on.  That's one reason (of many) people continually ask for a proper [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: ... So, if `volume` doesn't work, then you can hardcode it into the series info as needed.  Or not: many styles are happy just to mention the series title, and don't actually care about the volume number of any one member of the series.

Comment: @jon Please check my update. I did not know that the .bst was important to figure out the BibTeX category, sorry.

Comment: @jon After having seen the `.bst` file, do you agree with any of the answers?

Comment: Well, I typically prefer to use `biblatex`, but Mico's answer will be the easiest solution for you.  If you require the series editors, you need a different `.bst` or modify the current one (not easy unless you know what you're doing); `biblatex` is a whole new system, much improved over traditional BibTeX, but it might require more changes to your document than you wish.  (Note that BibTeX ignores fields its not instructed to use by the `.bst`, so you can leave `editor` as is or change it to something like `serieseditor`, which would be for your information, not for anything in the output.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using biblatex (and biber) compiles normally:

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article} %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{heuristica}

\usepackage{csquotes}%
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, firstinits, backend = biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{testbookinseries.bib}

\begin{document}

Blahblahblah
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the contents of the .blg:

```
[0] Config.pm:318> INFO - This is Biber 1.8
[0] Config.pm:321> INFO - Logfile is 'citebookinseries.blg'
[131] biber-MSWIN:272> INFO - === %a %b %e, %Y, %H:%M:%S
[131] Biber.pm:333> INFO - Reading 'citebookinseries.bcf'
[240] Biber.pm:607> INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0
[289] Biber.pm:3053> INFO - Processing section 0
[339] Biber.pm:3190> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'testbookinseries.bib' for section 0
[539] bibtex.pm:937> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
[542] bibtex.pm:812> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'E:/Tests/Biblatex/testbookinseries.bib'
[614] Biber.pm:2939> INFO - Overriding locale 'English_United States.1252' default tailoring 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[614] Biber.pm:2945> INFO - Sorting 'entry' list 'nyt' keys
[614] Biber.pm:2949> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'English_United States.1252'
[620] bbl.pm:482> INFO - Writing 'citebookinseries.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
[622] bbl.pm:555> INFO - Output to citebookinseries.bbl
```

Comment: Yes, it compiles, but does it compile *without any warning*?

Comment: Absolutely. I add the .blg at once

Comment: But that is wrong: With `biblatex`, the series volume number is indicated by `number`, and the editors are the series editors, which is not indicated in your example....

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, that is good news. However, I will wait for a little while before accepting this as an answer; I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Jon: I did not specify any style as you can notice, and did not check the exact contents of the bibliography item. I'll check that.

Comment: @Ali -- If you switch to `biblatex`, then `number` corresponds to the `series`, while `volume` corresponds to the volume of the `{book,main}title`.

Comment: Sure, I was referring to default biblatex entry fields, not style-specific ones.  The distinction between `volume` and `number` for `@Book` entries is well-documented.  I only mention it because this is important to know when one switches to `biblatex`.

Comment: @Bernard Please check my update. I did not know that the .bst was important to figure out the BibTeX category, sorry.

Comment: @Ali: No problem. In my mind, it was more of a suggestion, but I wanted to show it does work. What exactr bib style would you like to have? Do you want the editor function to be mentioned, and the volume be mentioned as `Vol. 5` or something like that?

Comment: @Bernard I don't really care how it appears. I just want to make sure that I am using the correct BibTeX category and either fix the warning or make sure it is safe to ignore it.

Comment: With biblatex, you won't have any warning, and `series` and  `editor` are indeed optional fields for the `@book` entry. See p. 7 of the doc. I looked at a brief description of `elsev-harvard` bibtex style, and the closest biblatex style seeems to be `authoryear`. I added that to my answer. Moreover, biblatex styles are relatively easy to customise.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if you use the `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style, it does not matter if you use the `@book` or the `@incollection` entry type for the entry at hand and the fields you've provided. (The fact that the editors of the series aren't shown for either entry type is a consequence of the bibliography style you've chosen. By the way, you can ignore the warnings.)

Using either entry type, you'll get the exact same output when using `elsarticle-harv`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Seydel10,
  AUTHOR = {R{\"u}diger Seydel},
  EDITOR = {S. S. Antman and L. Sirovich and J. E. Marsden},
  TITLE = {{Practical Bifurcation and Stability Analysis}},
  SERIES = {Interdisciplinary Applied Mathematics},
  VOLUME = {5},
  YEAR = {2010},
  PUBLISHER = {Dordrecht, The Netherlands: Springer},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\begin{document}
\citet{Seydel10}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent! I already upvoted your answer yesterday evening, many thanks. I decided to accept Bernard's answer because he "only" has 9.3k reputation points.